# Eigenvector problem with ellipsoids (maximizing quadratic form)

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, projection, qcqp

Let $B$ be a symmetric, positive definite matrix and consider the problem

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & x^\top B x\\ \text{subject to} & \|x\| = 1\\ & b^\top x = 0\end{array}$$

for some unit vector $b$, not necessarily an eigenvector of $B$. If $b$ is an eigenvector, this is easy: just pick the largest eigenvalue among all eigenvectors orthogonal to $b$. But what if $b$ is not an eigenvector?

My intuition is as follows. Let $z_i$ be the eigenvectors of $B$ (with corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda_i$. Each eigenvector can be projected onto the orthogonal complement of $b$ by taking the vector rejection

$$\hat{b}_i = z_i - \left(b^\top z_i\right)b$$

I believe that the maximizer should be one of the $\hat{b}_i$ vectors, but I don't know how to prove it or how to further characterize the right $i$. I guess that it should depend on both $\lambda_i$ and $(b^\top z_i)^2$, but don't know how to proceed further. Would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried using Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: Some characterizations of this maximum (which is, in a sense, the maximal eigenvalue of a "submatrix") can be obtained from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.03795.pdf).

Comment: if $b=0$ and the $||\cdot||_\infty$-norm is used, this problem is known to be NP-complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to the problem is as follows: extend $b$ into an orthonormal basis, so that $b,v_2,\dots,v_{n}$.  Note that for any unit vector $y \in \Bbb R^{n-1}$, the matrix $Qy$ is a vector in $b^\perp$. Conversely, every unit vector $x \in b^\perp$ can be expressed as $Qy$ for some vector $y \in \Bbb R^{n-1}$.

So, we can reframe your question as
$$
\max_{\|y\| = 1}(Qy)^TB(Qy) = \max_{\|y\| = 1}y^T (Q^TBQ)y.
$$
In other words, the maximum that we want is the largest eigenvalue of $Q^TBQ$.

The Courant-Fischer theorem tells us that this maximum will necessarily fall between (or be equal to one of) the two largest eigenvalues of $B$.

---

It does not necessarily hold that the maximum is equal to the projection of the eigenvector. As an example, consider
$$
B = \pmatrix{3&0&0\\ 0&2&0\\ 0&0&1}, \quad b = (1,1,1)/\sqrt{3} \implies\\
Q = \pmatrix{1/\sqrt{2}&1/\sqrt{6}\\-1/\sqrt{2}&1/\sqrt{6}\\0&-2/\sqrt{6}}, \quad Q^TBQ = \pmatrix{5/2 & 1/\sqrt{12}\\ 1/\sqrt{12} & 2/3}.
$$
The maximizer here is $y = v/\|v\|$, with $v = (\frac 16 (11 \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{399}), 1)$. You can verify that $x = Qy$ is not the projection of $(1,0,0)$ onto $b^\perp$.

Comment: Thanks! I am wondering if it might be possible to use a similar technique to derive a lower bound on x^\top B x when the condition is b^\top x = a for some small a \neq 0. Since any such x must take the form ab + \hat{x} with \hat{x} orthogonal to b, I conjecture that the lower bound should be (a^2)*\lambda_1 + (1 - a^2)*\lambda_2. The second term is by analogy with what you showed, and I think there should be some "inverse" relationship between how close \hat{x} is to the second eigenvector vs. how close b is. Just wondering if you might have some thoughts.